# Pointer to structure NOT changing at all when passed to function

Tags: c, struct, stack, structure

### **stack.h**

```
 #define MAX_STACK 10
 typedef int STACK_ITEM;
 typedef struct Stack *STACK ;
```

### **stack.c**

```
 #include"stack.h"

struct Stack{
    STACK_ITEM contents[MAX_STACK];
    int tos;
};

_Bool create_stack(STACK s){
    s = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    if(s == NULL )
        return 0;
    s->tos = 0;
    return 1;
}
```

When calling the `create_stack` function, it doesn't affect `s` (pointer to structure) at all. So, my question is: why is `s` **not** changing, even though it is a pointer, not a value, passed?

Comment: Because the function overwrites the *copy* of the value passed, which is forgotten when the function ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, all parameters are passed by value in C.

When you pass a pointer as a function parameter, you can access the object (or array of objects) pointed to by that pointer.

Your `create_stack()` is passed a pointer to a `struct Stack`, that is the `s` parameter.  It then *ignores* the original value of `s` and reassigns it. That is allowed, but note that it *does not change* the original pointer in the caller of `create_stack()` because function parameters are *passed by value*.

There are two ways to do what you want.

The first way is to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
_Bool create_stack(STACK *s){
    *s = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    if(*s == NULL )
        return 0;
    (*s)->tos = 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Call it e.g.:

```
STACK mystack;
_Bool ret;

ret = create_stack(&mystack);
if (!ret) {
    /* error */
}
```

The second way is to not pass anything and return a pointer to the allocated stack:

```
STACK create_stack(void){
    STACK s = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    if(s != NULL ) {
        s->tos = 0;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Call it e.g.:

```
STACK s;

s = create_stack();
if (s == NULL) {
    /* error */
}
```

Finally, as a point of programming style, do not `typedef` pointers in the way you have done. It is clearer if the pointer is explicit, for example, use `typedef struct Stack STACK;` instead of `typedef struct Stack *STACK;` and adjust the usage accordingly, for example, replacing `STACK s` with `STACK *s` and replacing `STACK *s` with `STACK **s`.

Answer (score 1):

Function parameters are its local variables. That is the parameters hold copies of the passed arguments. To change an original argument in a function you have to pass it by reference through pointer.

So change the function like

```
_Bool create_stack(STACK *s){
    *s = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    if(*s == NULL )
        return 0;
    ( *s )->tos = 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for a `C` function to modify an argument, the argument must be given as a pointer to the value to be changed. Thus, for a simple integer argument:

```
void Inc(int *value) {
    ++(*value);
}
```

will do the trick, but:

```
void Inc(int value) {
    ++value;
}
```

will do absolutely nothing to any argument given in a call to `Inc`, as the function just gets a copy of the 'value' given.

The same goes for a pointer! Your function just changes a ***copy*** of the pointer it is passed. So, you should change your function to take a pointer to the pointer:

```
_Bool create_stack(STACK *s){ // Pointer to a pointer to Stack
    *s = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack)); // Change the value of the STACK object pointed to
    if (*s == NULL )
        return 0;
    (*s)->tos = 0; // And, again, we need to (singly) dereference to 'double' pointer
    return 1;
}
```

Then, in your calling code, where you originally have something like:

```
_Bool answer = create_stack(myStackPointer);
```

you would need to add the address of your pointer:

```
_Bool answer = create_stack(&myStackPointer);
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.